# Machine learning not predicting correct results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working on creating a simple python machine learning script which will predict if loan will be approved or not based on below parameters

```
business experience: should be greater than 7
year of founded: should be after 2015
loan: no previous or current loan
```

If above conditions matches, then only loan will be approved. This dataset can be downloaded from this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtJ3EED7KDqJDrSHxHB6g9kc5YAfTlmF/view?usp=sharing

For above data, I have below script

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
data.head()

X = data[["Business Exp", "Year of Founded", "Previous/Current Loan"]]
Y = data["OUTPUT"]

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X, Y)

test_x2 = np.array([[9, 2017, 0]])
Y_pred = clf.predict(test_x2)
print(Y_pred)
```

I am passing the test data in `test_x2`. Test data is if business exp is 9, year of founded is 2017 and no current/previous loan, so that means loan will be provided. So it should predict and the result should be `1` but it shows 0. Is there any issue with the code or with the dataset. As I am newbie in machine learning and still learning it so I have created this custom dataset for my own understanding.

Please can anyone give some good suggestions. Thanks

Comment: If you have exact criteria for determining whether a loan is approved, why are you using machine learning? `if biz_exp > 7 and founded > 2015 and prior_loans == 0` should exactly "predict" whether a loan is approved.

Comment: @TomMcLean Can you please suggest any other model

Comment: @ddejohn I have a lot of other parameters with lot of values for them. I dont want to start with high amount of data, so I am just starting with less data so that I have good understanding

Comment: Well a machine learning model is never exact. What other tests have you run? Have you checked the [ROC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve? Perhaps your model performs better than you think?

Comment: @TomMcLean why? Because of the dimensionality of the input?

Comment: OP, see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification#Statistical_binary_classification) article for other binary classification models you could look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use StandardScaler() within a pipeline

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
data.head()

X = data[["Business Exp", "Year of Founded", "Previous/Current Loan"]]
Y = data["OUTPUT"]

clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
clf.fit(X, Y)

test_x2 = np.array([[9, 2017, 0]])
Y_pred = clf.predict(test_x2)
```

```
print("prediction = ", Y_pred.item())
prediction =  1
print("score = ", clf.score(X, Y))
score =  0.95535
```

Comment: Just wanted to know how we can print how much the model accuracy?

Comment: Use score function.